# Web Proxy like Optimizely

Tags: python, http, proxy, tornado, python-requests

I'm trying to write a proxy like Optimizely. If you go to `http://optimizely.com` you can try Optimizely on any site. Here's an example: `https://www.optimizely.com/edit#url=espn.com`.

I've dissected the page a little, and notice the actual URL that acts as a proxy is at edit.optimizely.com: http://edit.optimizely.com/http://espn.go.com/?optimizely_compatibility=false&optimizely_disable=true

Many requests on this page go back to edit.optimizely.com/{uri}, and it seems like they use cookies to preserve the actual domain (you can see in the cookies there's `last_path=http://espn.go.com/;`) and the url is proxied on the server.

I wrote a tornado app that uses [requests][2] as a proxy that acts in a similar way to the Optimizely proxy, but I know that's not the intention of requests, and it fails on many websites. I'm wondering the "correct" way of implementing something similar. I know I can write a proxy easily using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.web.proxy.html) and then change my global proxy settings on my system to use it, but I'm not sure how I'd write an app that returns the contents of espn.com by going to: `http://localhost:8000/http://espn.com` without abusing something like requests...(ie `return requests.get('http://espn.com').content`

How would I deal with content-types, content-lengths, other misc. headers, delivering the data back to the user...

Comment: Here's essentially what I have now for server.py: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8d97c69d2a8cdc52921a and filehelpers.py: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0e1779b32ecb080d813f so if you have these two files and you run server.py and go to http://localhost:8889/http://espn.com/?start=true it works. I don't think this is really the "proper" way to do this. And this doesn't work for many sites that Optimizely does work for...

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure how to do this with tornado (I have absolutely 0 experience with it) but I can give you an example in Flask.

First of all, I don't think there is anyway to write a proxy that would allow you to do `http://localhost:8000/http://espn.com`. Note, for example, that Optimizely doesn't use `http://espn.com` but just `espn.com`. We will do the same.

If you're unfamiliar with Flask, it's a very simple. Here's a proof that you can do `localhost:8000/espn.com`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<uri>')
def fake_proxy(uri):
    return uri

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Saving that in a file, say `proxy1.py` and then doing `python proxy1.py` will start the debugging server and you'll be able to go to (in a browser) `http://localhost:5000/espn.com` and it will print `espn.com` to your browser. Succcess!

To simply display the contents of a web-site all you need to do is `return requests.get('http://' + uri).content`. I'm not certain what content-type is set by default in Flask, but you don't need to worry since most browsers will detect the HTML and display it properly.

If you want to be exact about this, look into [Flask's documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/), specifically about [responses](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#about-responses) and get to work.

Now, if you want to deploy this, you'll have to use something else than the debugging server (i.e. how you're running it now), so you'll have to look into different solutions, e.g., gunicorn, celery, etc.

If you want to continue doing it in Twisted, I'm certain Twisted's docs are fantastic and that it can't be much more difficult than this particular Flask app.

Note, if you ever think you'll forget how this works, just add a route for '/' and return some usage info. It doesn't even need html formatting to work.

---

**Edit**

After a comment by OP, I've realized I didn't fully understand his question. Here is an attempt to do better.

To properly set Content-Types, Content-Lengths and other headers, you'll need to actually save the Response object from requests. Take for example the following code:

```
 import requests

 r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
```

Now look at the headers attribute:

```
 r.headers
```

Is  a dictionary (which can be accessed case-insensitively) of the headers returned on the response. One header that will be there is the `Set-Cookie` header (assuming the site you're scraping sets a cookie).

Since you're also setting a cookie, you need to properly construct your new cookie so it won't interfere with the site's and can be appended properly as the RFCs intended.

Your dictionary there will have the `Content-Length`, `Content-Type`, and all other headers they deem necessary to send. Forward them as you please.

Also, I didn't  play with Optimizely a great deal, but I assume that by clicking links on the page you didn't leave their site. With my naive example above, you do end up leaving the proxy. That said, you seem to already be handling that case as it is, so you don't need my help with that.

As for how Optimizely actually does what they do, I suspect they're using a great deal of JavaScript to laad, edit and display it. Everything seems to go through an "internal" API they have designed for its use (`edit.optimizely.com`) so not everything is happening in one place.

I know neither how their API was designed, nor how it works, but I suspect you could sniff the traffic and probably play with it if you received enough intercepted packets to determine what they're doing and what the API looks like.

As for whether or not requests is the proper library for this: requests is (supposedly, I've never tested it myself) much faster than urllib2. It works well in threaded and non-threaded (or greenlet) situations. If you utilize the session object, all the cookies set by `espn.com` (for example) will be saved and your navigation won't be hampered by ESPN noticing you don't have cookies set. But really we can not tell you whether it is the right library for the tool you're building. That's entirely your call.

Comment: Thanks for the response sigmavirus24! So I've gotten that far with my server, and I actually do use http:// or https:// (depending on the uri in the request) to allow for both secure and insecure requests. I even set a cookie, like Optimizely does, for the path so I can resolve relative links in the page that's returned. The question is really, how do I do this the "right" way. I feel like I'm abusing the requests library. It's not intended to be used as a proxy, and tornado might not be the best solution for the web framework either. I'm more or less wondering exactly how Optimizely does this

Comment: Ah, @KangRoodle, I see that your question is vastly different than I thought it was. I'll try and edit my answer to include that, although I can only speculate about Optimizely.

Comment: I added a comment to show you basically what I have now...